# Payment in Single page application (Vue)

Tags: forms, vue.js, payment

I have payment form in my spa app like this:

```
<form  Method='post' Action='https://pep.shaparak.ir/gateway.aspx'>
    invoiceNumber<input type='text' name='invoiceNumber' v-model='InvoiceNumber' />
    invoiceDate<input type='text' name='invoiceDate' v-model='InvoiceDate' />
    amount<input type='text' name='amount' v-model='Amount' />
    terminalCode<input type='text' name='terminalCode' v-model='TerminalCode' />
    merchantCode<input type='text' name='merchantCode' v-model='MerchantCode' />
    redirectAddress<input type='text' name='redirectAddress' v-model='RedirectAddress' />
    timeStamp<input type='text' name='timeStamp' v-model='TimeStamp' />
    action<input type='text' name='action' v-model='Action' />
    sign<input type='text' name='sign' v-model='Sign' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Checkout' @click="Checkout()" />
</form>
```

and

```
Checkout: function(){
    axios.get('./api/pasargad').then(response => {
        var vm = this;
        vm.InvoiceNumber = response.data.InvoiceNumber;
        vm.InvoiceDate = response.data.InvoiceDate;
        vm.Amount = response.data.Amount;
        vm.TerminalCode = response.data.TerminalCode;
        vm.MerchantCode = response.data.MerchantCode;
        vm.RedirectAddress = response.data.RedirectAddress;
        vm.TimeStamp = response.data.TimeStamp;
        vm.Action = response.data.Action;
        vm.Sign = response.data.Sign;


        }.bind(vm));
    });
},
```

i need to run this steps when i click the Checkout() function:

1. First get data
2. run the action of form(redirect to gateway page)

but in this example first redirect to gateway with unknown data!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should prevent default submitting a form and then add another Axios call inside a function.
`<form v-on:submit.prevent>`

and `checkout` should look like this,

```
Checkout: function(){
    var vm = this;
    axios.get('./api/pasargad').then(response => {
        vm.InvoiceNumber = response.data.InvoiceNumber;
        vm.InvoiceDate = response.data.InvoiceDate;
        vm.Amount = response.data.Amount;
        vm.TerminalCode = response.data.TerminalCode;
        vm.MerchantCode = response.data.MerchantCode;
        vm.RedirectAddress = response.data.RedirectAddress;
        vm.TimeStamp = response.data.TimeStamp;
        vm.Action = response.data.Action;
        vm.Sign = response.data.Sign;


        }.bind(vm));
    });
    axios.post('https://pep.shaparak.ir/gateway.aspx',vm)
},
```